Is there a way to change the font for the whole phone system from my app? (Android/Java)
I'm trying to make a custom keyboard app, which also allows to change the font with which you are typing. Does anyone know any way to change the font of the whole phone system from it?
I tried searching for other variants but all of them were just fancy text, not custom fonts.

Changing the system-wide font on the phone programmatically from your app is not officially supported in Android.

Most likely you can't, you can change the font weight or color sometimes or underline it if the text box or text area component supports it, there are a limited number of fonts installed in the Android system and they are carefully selected fonts that support most of the world's languages, it is difficult to provide multiple font families for each language.
Another reason is that most text boxes/text areas do not support rich text with its full features, and changing the font family requires supporting rich text.
Most applications that support multiple font families each have their own way of implementing multiple fonts, such as Microsoft Word and Xodo.
As for changing the font for the entire operating system, this is more difficult and requires root permissions and may cause the operating system to crash and enter into an infinite reboot, it is practically impossible.
